# Не получается запустить React-приложение на WebStorm

Tags: webstorm

Дело в WebStorm, потому как в VS code запуск успешен

Cannot open Local Terminal
Failed to start [cmd.exe] in C:\my_codes\samurai_path\projects\01_first_project\react-way-of-samurai

Error running process: Agent shutdown due to RPC failure. Code 0

See your idea.log (Help | Show Log in Explorer) for the details.

Comment: добавьте лог, пожалуйста

Comment: извините, какой лог?

Comment: сюда нельзя скинуть лог, потому что файлы загрузить нет в интерфейсе. Что делать?

Comment: Откройте лог, найдите и скопируйте место связанное с вашей ошибкой и вставьте его.